# JPA (Eclipselink impl) lazy fetch outside transaction

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using glassfish and Java EE 6. I have created a restful web service with Jersey that performs searching operations on a `Comment` table. Each comment has an `Author`.

I have a `@Stateless`, `@Path('comments')` EJB listening on Http requests. I then have this method:

```
@GET
@Path("search")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public List<Comment> getComments(@QueryParam("criteria").....)
```

My JPA query fetches a bunch of comments. Each comment has an association to its Author, that is also fetched since it's not set to LAZY, but except for his ID, most of the Author's fields are not retrieved (e.g The Author's name) even though I tried setting them to `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`. This gets retrieved when I do something like:

```
comment.getAuthor().getName()
```

But this works if I am inside a transaction so the Persistence Context is alive throughout the execution of my method. However, I don't want to use a transaction here since this is just searching the Database and not changing any data (hence the `@TransactionAttribute(...NOT_SUPPORTED)`), so when I call the getter above I simply get a "null" (no data is fetched), and I don't know how to work this out.

I don't want to use a Transaction, but I want Eclipselink to fetch the attributes of the Author eagerly.

EDIT:

Since I'm not within a transaction, put simply, what I want is for eclipselink to retrieve my "comment.author.name" field for every comment I get from my query.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this for now using Non-standard Eclipselink "LoadGroup" capabilities:

```
LoadGroup lg = new LoadGroup();
lg.addAttribute("author.name");
query.setHint(QueryHints.LOAD_GROUP, lg);
result = query.getResultList();
```

I'm looking for a standard solution though.